# How many times I have to tell you?

Tags: riddle

> If you do THIS you are noisy
>
> So you take the front out -- you are still noisy
>
> Now you take the middle out? -- still noisy!
>
> Next one out -- nothing changed
>
> Taking the end out? -- I can still hear you.

**What is this verb?**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are:

> **SHOOT** - a noisy thing to do indeed.

So you take the front out -- you are still noisy

> A **HOOT** is a noisy noise

Now you take the middle out? -- still noisy!

> A **SHOT** is still noisy - just the noun instead of a verb

Next one out -- nothing changed

> Same as above

Taking the end out? -- I can still hear you.

> **SHOO** is still a thing people say, to tell a noisy pest (yet again!) to go away!
>  Or, as @humn notes in comments, if "the end" refers to the entire end -OOT, it'd leave **SH**, a directive to be quiet!

Title

> See "SHOO" above.

Answer (score -2):

Is it

> YELL (as it goes most by pronounciation)

As,

If you do THIS you are noisy

> If you yell, you are noisy

So you take the front out -- you are still noisy

> take 'Y' out to get 'ell' (same pronounciation as YELL) and still sounds noisy!

Now you take the middle out? -- still noisy!

> There are two possibilities to take the middle out. So let us focus on only needed - the first 'L', resulting in 'YEL' ....which is still noisy (by saying, though not literally!)

Next one out -- nothing changed

> Next one out results in another 'YEL'

Taking the end out? -- I can still hear you.

> Taking the end out results in the same as above

And for the title,

> It is like expressing some kind of disgust/anger at someone, which could be by YELLING

Comment: Can you please explain?

Comment: @boboquack, provided my explanation.

Comment: By this reasoning, if part of a word is "noisy" because you can try to pronounce it aloud (even if it isn't a real word), then any word is a valid answer.

Comment: Well, @Mike Q,  can you please suggest any one such word.